# Why should I use PassportJS?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Looking in to making a simple Angular - Node app and of course I have come across PassportJS for auth. Looking at the website, I'm finding it difficult to understand why I need it or what it does for me?

My users will login using a username and password. Why can't I just find a matching record in the db, set a session if required and return a response? Why should/would I use Passport for this?

Comment: *"Why can't I just x, y and z?"* can be asked for pretty much any (non-native) library. Not having to write boilerplate code and having a system that might be easier to extend in the future potentially saves a lot of time, even if the library doesn't do anything too special.

Answer (score 4):

No real reason, if that's  all you want to do. Using passport starts to pay off when you start incorporating other authorization providers, such as Facebook, Twitter, google, etc.

Comment: Also it will take care of some boilerplate code you need to write for authentication, and in case you will want to connect some auth providers it will be very easy to extend without need for a complete auth logic rewrite.